# Merge two hashes of hashes, without overlap

Tags: ruby

I have two hashes of hashes that look basically like:

```
sales = { 
  "2013-03-15": {sales: 5}, 
  "2013-03-14": {sales: 3}, 
  "2013-03-12": {sales: 8},
  ... }
```

and

```
views = { 
  "2013-03-15": {views: 30}, 
  "2013-03-14": {views: 23}, 
  "2013-03-13": {views: 35}, 
  ... }
```

How can I merge them into a single hash that looks like:

```
data = { 
  "2013-03-15": {views: 30, sales: 5}, 
  "2013-03-14": {views: 23, sales: 3}, 
  "2013-03-13": {views: 35, sales: 0}, # or just {views: 35} 
  ... }
```

Basically, I need to keep the keys and all the data intact.

`data = views.merge sales` Seems to override all the views data, leaving me with basically just the sales hash.

**Edit:** I can also convert the sales or views hashes into simple hashes (not hashes of hashes), but I still don't know a good way to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
sales.merge(views) { |k, o, n| o.merge(n) }
```

Runnable example:

```
views = {
  "2013-03-15" => {:views=> 30},
  "2013-03-14" => {:views=> 23},
  "2013-03-13" => {:views=> 35},
}

sales = {
  "2013-03-15" => {:sales=> 5},
  "2013-03-14" => {:sales=> 3},
  "2013-03-12" => {:sales=> 8},
}

puts sales.merge(views) { |k, o, n| o.merge(n) }
=> {"2013-03-15"=>{:sales=>5, :views=>30}, "2013-03-14"=>{:sales=>3, :views=>23}, "2013-03-12"=>{:sales=>8}, "2013-03-13"=>{:views=>35}}
```